# UWP Application will support Application Insights or Not?

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-application-insights

I developed simple UWP application, in that I am trying to add the Application insights for tracking page views, events and exceptions etc...

I Installed the below packages from Nuget

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -----2.3.0

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps ----1.1.1

After Installed the above packages in UWP application and build the application but it gives the error like shown in below figure.

[image]

I know there is [hockey app](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-integrate-hockeyapp-with-application-insights) for tracking the events and exceptions etc.… instead of Application Insights. But one of my client asked like “Whether UWP application currently supports Application Insights or not”.

Answer (score 3):

Application Insights 2.x package does not support the UWP apps. To use the AI on UWP apps, following nuget packages are required:

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "1.2.3",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel": "1.2.3",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps": "1.1.1",
```

It's a copy of my UWP app's project.json. It works well with my UWP app and I can see the analytics data from AI dashboard.

Added - I've noticed that this is not an answer for “Whether UWP application currently supports Application Insights or not” :) Yes, MS guided several years ago that the hockey app will turn to the mainstream of UWP analytics. But the AI for UWP works yet - or just works. I'm not a right person for the question - MS guys can answer it maybe.